# How can I add asc and desc sort symbols?

Tags: views

I have a drupal 7 view, consists of table. I need to add sort symbol (both asc and desc)
in view header by default if no sorting applied.

I tried with altering views-view-table.tpl.php file, and added asc, desc images for each header.

But I need proper solution, Is there any hook there to alter the table headers?

Comment: you can add class to the table. Then you can do CSS

Answer (score 0):

Implement theme_tablesort_indicator(). Please replace your theme name with example

```
function example_tablesort_indicator($variables) {
  $style = $variables['style'];
  $theme_path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'example');
  if ($style == 'asc') {
    return theme('image', array('path' => $theme_path . '/images/arrow-asc.png', 'alt' => t('sort ascending'), 'width' => 13, 'height' => 13, 'title' => t('sort ascending')));
  }
  else {
    return theme('image', array('path' => $theme_path . '/images/arrow-desc.png', 'alt' => t('sort descending'), 'width' => 13, 'height' => 13, 'title' => t('sort descending')));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet without a lot of theming and template overrides, preprocessing and some JS is to use jquery TableSorter:

- https://www.drupal.org/project/tablesorter
- https://www.drupal.org/project/views_tablesorter

What you have linked to is actually an Angular based front end. TableSorter is the next closest thing without being Angular JS.